# ConcurrentModificationException while iterating through HashMap

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` while iterating through a HashMap.

How can I fix this?

```
public void stopAllPlaying(int fadeDurationInMs)
{
    for(PlayThread thread : threadMap.values()) {
        if(thread != null) {
            thread.fadeOut(fadeDurationInMs);
        }
    }
    threadMap.clear();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately using `lock` doesn't seem to have fixed it.  I've copied the error message below

```
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:796)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.example.myapp.AudioTrackPlayer.stopAllPlaying(AudioTrackPlayer.java:141)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.example.myapp.MyApp.stopAllSounds(MyApp.java:119)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.stopPlayback(MainActivity.java:114)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:451)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3397)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3542)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1121)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-06 01:05:51.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I needed to add the lock to all instances where the Hashmap was being modified!

Comment: Have you tried any synchronizing techiques? "synchronized" keyword, Lock, Semaphore, anything?

Comment: See my updated answer. I guess you missed a usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public void stopAllPlaying(int fadeDurationInMs)
{
    lock.lock();
    try{
      for(PlayThread thread : threadMap.values()) {
          if(thread != null) {
              thread.fadeOut(fadeDurationInMs);
          }
      }
      threadMap.clear();
    }
    finally{
    lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

This should do the job.

You must lock all other usages of threadMap in the same way **with the same Lock instance**.

NOTE: This is *not the only* way to do synchronization.

See also http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

You may find this helpful, too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Thanks Fildor - this works great. Any idea how efficient this is? Would locking the thread itself be better so wouldn't block my UI thread?

Comment: More efficient would be to use some lock-free algorithm. Personally I consider using a Lock pretty efficient as long as the locked block is small enough (in LOC and execution time). At least it is more efficient than locking the whole instance using the synchronized keyword.

Comment: I do not really know what you mean with "locking the thread itself". Actually you _are_ "locking the thread". I.e. If Thread1 has entered the locked block, Thread2 will block at `lock.lock()` until Thread1 releases the lock with `lock.unlock()`.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't the right terminology. I meant instead I could put a `thread.isStopping = true` flag and then not allow `thread.fadeOut()` to run if so

Comment: I do not think thread.fadeOut is the problem. threadMap.clear() changes the datastructure. So if Thread2 is already iterating on that and Thread1 clears it, the iterator will throw the exception. With the lock, you make sure it is processed once, then cleared. The second Thread will not enter the loop, because threadMap has no elements at that time.

Comment: Hi again, actually with more testing it doesn't seem to have worked.  I've updated my question.  Could you take a look please?

Comment: @fxfuture You have to lock _all_ usages of the datastructure with **the same Lock instance**. Did you do that? For example, the place where you add to threadMap.

Comment: No I didn't do that. I'm adding to and removing from the hashmap in several different methods. So they all need lock.lock() and lock.unlock() surrounding them in the same way?

Comment: Wouldn't making the methods `synchronized` work instead?  It's just the UI thread calling those methods

Comment: Yes, you have to surround all (modifying) usages with lock/unlock. Using `synchronized` keyword, you'll have to synchronize all methods containing a modifying call on the threadMap, locking the whole class instance. You _can_ do that. I consider it less efficient, though. To proof that, you'd have to benchmark it of course. But if in doubt, I prefer locks before synchronized keyword.

Comment: No it doesn't but I have `stopNote()` which also removes from the hashmap.  So maybe this is the problem - this is happening at the same time as `stopAllSounds()`  I see there is ConcurrentHashMap and SynchronizedMap

Comment: Good find of those two. SynchronizedMap will not help you since it only syncs single calls. The iterator will still "fail fast". About ConcurrentHashMap, I'm not sure. If I remember correctly it will at least not throw an exception.

Comment: Docu sais " Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time." So, you may not get an exception but work on an outdated state.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap worked fine but there were performance issues so I'm going to use your locking method which I now understand how it works. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lock the GUI thread for long as this stalls all application. "fadeOut" does not sound as something instant.

Cascade the two threads: GUI thread calls the intermediate thread and this intermediate thread then calls `stopAllPlaying`, waiting for the lock if necessary. The intermediate thread can wait for arbitrary long time.

Comment: Thanks Audruis but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you kindly provide a code example?